# How can I transform a node module, including its dependencies with babel?

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, babeljs, ipfs

My web app does not work on ie11 because of [ipfs-api](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api).

This module uses ES6 and has not been transpiled.
Some dependencies are not transpiled, too.
And some dependencies of those dependencies are not transpiled, and so on...

How can I transpile ipfs-api and related modules?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/) here.

Just add something like this at the start of your entrypoint:

```
require("babel-register")({
  only: /node_modules\/package-name/
});
```

Keep in mind it would bring the whole babel runtime at the start of application, which can increase application's start up time.